# How to load external assets (image, stylesheets, etc) when using html-pdf in Node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs

I'm using `html-pdf` ([NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)) to generate PDF files in my Node.js app. The way I'm doing it, is first I render the HTML content using Handlebars and then feed the resulting buffer to `html-pdf`'s `create()` method. Like this:

```
var pdfProperties = {
    format: "A4"
}

fs.readFile('views/project-evaluation-print.hbs', {encoding: 'utf8'}, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    var source = data;
    var html = render(source, pageParameters);
    htmlPdf.create(html, pdfProperties).toStream(function(err, stream) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        stream.pipe(res);
    });
});
```

I'm using Express, and I serve my assets via routes for each type. So I load them onto a regular HTML like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/home-page.css">
<img src="/images/logos/app-logo.png">
```

The problem is, these fail to load when the PDF is generated. I tried doing it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="localhost:8080/stylesheets/home-page.css">
<img src="localhost:8080/images/logos/app-logo.png">
```

I've also tried adding `base` property to `pdfProperties`

```
var pdfProperties = {
    format: "A4",
    base: "http://localhost:8080/"
}
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. I should set `pdfProperties.base` to `http://localhost:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080/` (no trailing slash).

Or set it dynamically to `req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')`.

Comment: Thanks. Really helped a lot. Did not want to use CDN's in this pdf render.